# Python/Bokeh: Disable hover tool for hidden glyphs (via interactive legend)

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

### Problem description

Since bokeh 0.12.5 it is possible to use [interactive legends](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/legends.html) to hide or mute glyphs via clicking on them in the legend box. This is a great feature especially for more complex plots.

However, when used in conjunction with the [hover tool](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hovertool), hidden glyphs should not trigger the hover tool because the user is provided with a tooltip for glyphs which are not visible (due to muting via the interactive legend).

Here is minimal code example for clarification:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook

x = np.arange(0, 10, 1)

p = figure(tools=["hover"])
p.line(x, x, legend="Line 1")
p.line(x, x/2, legend="Line 2")

p.legend.click_policy = "hide"
show(p)
```

This is the resulting plot (without hiding):
[image]

This is the plot with Line 2 being hidden but having an active hover tooltip:[image]

### Question

Is there an option I'm currently missing to deactivate hover tooltips for hidden glyphs? If not, does anyone can think of a short workaround (perhaps employing CustomCS)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of bokeh 0.12.6, it is fixed. For more, see the issue in the github repo [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6120).