# Python/Bokeh: Hover tool does not display when hiding glyphs via interactive legend

Tags: python, bokeh

When utilizing the interactive legend I noticed that hiding a glyph would prevent the hover tool from reading glyphs below it in the legend. IE if I have three lines listed as line1, line2, and line3 then I hide line2 via the interactive legend the hover tool will not work for line3 but it will work for line1.

Example code snippet

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook

x = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
x2 = x/2
x3=x/4

p = figure(tools=["hover"])
p.line(x, x, legend="Line 1")
p.line(x, x2, legend="Line 2")
p.line(x, x3, legend='Line 3')

p.legend.click_policy = "hide"
show(p)
```

No hidden glyphs
[image: No hidden glyphs]

Hide line2 and hover tool doesn't work for line3[image]

But hover tool still works for line1[image]

I'm assuming this is a bug related to the previous issue where the hover tool would still display hidden glyphs as seen [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6120) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408571/python-bokeh-disable-hover-tool-for-hidden-glyphs-via-interactive-legend).

**QUESTION**

Any chance someone can think of a workaround for this bug?

Thanks!

Comment: When I run your code I have the expected behavior. I can hide any line and the hovertool still works for other lines. Might a version specific issue

Comment: Can I ask what version of Bokeh and Python you are running?  I'm currently running a WinPython distribution 3.6.5 and Bokeh 0.12.15.  I know Bokeh has a 0.12.16 so I'll try upgrading and see if that works.

Comment: I mostly use 0.12.10 with python 2.7; might have been a regression in between .10 and .16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seb answered the question and it was due to me running Bokeh v0.12.15 instead of the latest v0.12.16

Once I updated Bokeh it worked like a charm.

Silly of me to not be running the latest version.